# acess and modify activity content in a different activity

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to create an Activity that configures content from all the others activities, the app I'm working on is designed for children and will contain a lot of games, but it is up to the children's parent to determine which games they will play as well as the game's configuration, so I need to create a "Game Configuration" that manages all of the activities and their views.

For instance: There's an activity called "Game list" that has an ArrayList with an ArrayAdapter, from the activity called "Config" I want to be able to acess the ArrayList and choose with games will be played when clicked in one of the buttons of the list as well as adding more nodes/Games to the list. It's kind of block-based programming.

I have little idea (AsyncTask and etc) on how to acess the ArrayList, but I don't know how to refresh it  and save the modification when the app is closed. So, how do I (properly) access the ArrayList from a different class and then refresh it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying to modify Activities from other Activities is a terrible idea. You should instead be persisting the user's configuration somehow (SQLite maybe, or shared preferences) and having the other activities load their content based on the persisted configuration. There is no Activity-to-Activity communication with this approach.

Comment: you mean like saving the arraylist in a database, override it when modified and then retrieving it in the activity it is used? Sounds ok to me, but do you have any example of how to implement it?

Comment: alright, one last question though: can i use the SQLite to save all kinds of data? (like onclicklistener, content and instances)

Comment: SQLite doesn't store java objects. It stores text, numeric data, and raw bytes (as BLOBs). How you define your database schema and how you interpret the data you store is entirely up to you. http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html